# Routes is not working react-router-dom V6

Tags: reactjs

I am npm install react-router-dom@6.0.0-alpha.2
but don't work this Routes is not working help ....

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import login from './pages/login';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/">
          dashboard
        </Route> 
      <Route exact path="/login" component={login}/>
      <Route path="*" render={() => "404 Not found!"}/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: RRv6 has breaking changes. You'll have to modify your code to work with the new version. I suggest following their upgrade guide - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Comment: Also, why install the alpha version? You should use a stable version of v6

Answer (score 0):

In react router v6 you must use **element** prop, I guess you are wrapping app in `index.js` with `<BrowserRouter>` and `login` should be in capital letter if it is a component, like this `Login` and exact is not supported in react router v6

```
    import './App.css';
    import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import login from './pages/login';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1>Dashboard</h1>}/>
          <Route path="/login" element={<login/>}/>
          <Route path="*" element={<h1>404 Not found!</h1>}/>
        </Routes>
      );
    }
 
    export default App;
```

Comment: <Route path="/login" element={<login/>}/>
this code is error and Direct file project_name>src>pages>login.js